# Move a line on an image with the help of for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, line, draw

I want to move a line on an image. In-fact I am using a loop. When I draw a new line, previous line should be deleted. But I don't know how to delete the previous line. I tried using invalidate and dispose methods but it did not work. My code is:

```
           int xinc = 0, yinc = 0;                
           for (int loop = 0; loop <= 363; loop++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);

            MethodInvoker actionimage1 = delegate
            {
                Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                if (loop <= 117)
                {
                    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 4.0f);
                    g.DrawLine(p, 0, xinc, 363, xinc);
                    g.Clear(this.BackColor);
                    this.Dispose();
                    this.Invalidate();

                    xinc++;
                }

                if (loop <= 363)
                {
                    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 4.0f);
                    g.DrawLine(p, yinc, 0, yinc, 117);
                    g.Clear(this.BackColor);
                    this.Dispose(); // I need here to remove the line, 
                                      such that when loop starts again the 
                                      sholud be on next coordinate. 
                    this.Invalidate();

                    yinc++;
                }

                };
            pictureBox1.BeginInvoke(actionimage1);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether you are working with canvas or some other
   technology. Anyways, here is the generic answer

- If you are working with bitmap (canvas), you can't modify the location of a
  line like modifying an object location because everything is pixel.
- Instead you can have the initial image (input) be redrawn before drawing a
  line on it.

  Just curious to know, What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks sandeep. I am using form and a picturebox. image is shown in picturebox1. I want to move the line on the image using loop, horizontally and vertically. in current code lines are not removed. is that clear now?

Comment: You need to redraw the entire image (initial) since you are projecting it as bitmap. On top of that you can draw the line (pixels)

Comment: but i dont want to redraw the image. there must be some other solution. what I am thinking is that I am doing some error in dispose or invalidate etc.